# Setting SSL login session with apache and plone for secure login

Tags: apache, ssl, plone, plone-3.x

I am try to force an SSL session after login.  The login part works forceing the connection initially to SSL.  But after goes back to normal http after login.  For all other Browser expect IE.

From

`http://plone.org/documentation/kb/apache-ssl`

I have the below working with IE.  But does not work with FireFox and Chrome. I am running apache 2.2.2 and Plone 3.5.

## Redirect to https if the __ac cookie is set

`RewriteCond ${HTTPS} off`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} __ac=`

`RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [NE,L]`

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

## Redirect to https if the __ac cookie is set

`RewriteCond ${HTTPS} "!=on"`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} __ac=`
`RewriteRule ^($|/.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [NE,L]`